# How to respond the reviewer who reject my paper but editor ask to revise

Tags: publications

The editor asked me to revise my paper and answer the reviewers' questions. Two of three reviewers asked me to revise some parts and agree that it is quite new and can improve it but one of them reject my paper in all parts e.g., contributions, research model. How can I response to the reviewer who rejected my paper? Do I need to email to editor to consult him?

Thank you very much

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The same way you respond to the reviewers who didn't reject your article: you take the reviewer's criticism and argue why it's irrelevant, inappropriate, unfair, has been fixed in the revision, and so on. If the reviewer rejected your article without giving reasons, then you can safely ignore the reviewer (since the editor decided on revise, he/she clearly already disregards the reviewer's report).

There's no need to email the editor.

Comment: Valuable comment

Comment: Please consider spending more time arguing how the reviewers criticisms have been fixed in the revision or are irrelevant, than spending time arguing why the reviewers criticisms are inappropriate or unfair.

Comment: You probably can argue that one or two of the criticisms are unfair but more than that makes you look bad - and it's best to not say that at all.  Treat each criticism seriously and professionally, and explain what you've done to improve the manuscript in response to each.